# Kernel Dimension Given by $\frac{n^2-n}{2}$?

Tags: linear-algebra

So this is part of a bigger problem I was solving, which all went well, except this part.

There is a linear transformation $S:M_{n \times n}^{\mathbb{R}} \rightarrow M_{n \times n}^{\mathbb{R}}$ defined as: $S(A)=\frac{A+A^t}{2}$.

I have found that the characteristic polynomial for this transformation is $x(x-1)^3$ and the minimal polynomial is: $x(x-1)$ by finding the matrix form of the transformation $([S]_E)$ and doing a direct calculation.

However, I found the solution to this problem, and the problem setter says that after you calculate the minimal polynomial, you can derive the characteristic polynomial by calculating the kernel dimensions using this formula:

$a=dimKerS=dim\{A:A^t=-A\}=\frac{n^2-n}{2}=1$
$b=dimKer(S-I)=dim\{A:A^t=A\}=\frac{n^2+n}{2}=3$

The left parts are understandable, but where did he get the $\frac{n^2-n}{2}$ from? I don't remember encountering such a theorem, or maybe it's some geometric meaning I'm forgetting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $A^t = -A$, then $a_{i,i} = 0$ for any $i$ and $a_{i,j} = -a_{j,i}$ for $i > j$. Therefore $A$ is uniquely determined by the entries $a_{i,j}$ with $i < j$ (i.e. from the upper triangle). How many elements are there in $\{ (i, j) \mid 1 \le i < j \le n \}$?

If $A^t = A$, the proof is similar.